# Network error: Connection timed out while connecting raspberry Pi via SSH using putty

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi with my laptop so that I may use my laptop mouse, screen and keyboard but its giving me error

> Network error: Connection timed out

These are the steps I have followed to connect raspberry pi to my laptop using putty

1. Power on the Raspberry PI and inserted one end of Ethernet cable to Raspberry Pi's `RJ-45` jack and other end to my PC's Ethernet Port.
2. Connected My PC with internet via WiFi and modified the Wi-Fi properties as shown.

[image]

3. Checked the IP of my network adapters by entering `ipconfig` command in the cmd.

[image]

> This is the screenshot to show active networks:

[image]

4. Then I scanned all the IP Addresses of my Ethernet network use advanced IP scanner

[image]

5. Then I entered the IP address in the puTTY and clicked open

[image]

6. After some time puTTY give an error `Network error: Connection timed out`.

[image]

**P.S.**

1. I have already enabled SSH from raspberry pi preferences.
2. After reading answer of [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/ssh-connection-timeout-when-connecting) question, I ping the IP of my Raspberry PI in which I was shown error there.

[image]

Can Anyone assist me in finding out what is the mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a question belonging mainly to MS Windows, not Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to use Internet Connect Sharing (ICS) on Windows to connect the Pi.

This works - to give internet access to the Pi.

Unfortunately this can not be used to provide `ssh` or `VNC` access to the Pi. You can have **EITHER** ICS **OR** `ssh` - not BOTH.

If you want to use `ssh` you have to disable ICS.

You would be better to connect the Pi to your router.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing for me. My PC was on 5 GHz band, Pi on 2.4 GHz band of router. Moved PC to 2.4 GHz, now I can Putty and CMD Ping to Pi ip.