# Headless connection Raspberry Pi , unable to ping/ssh

Tags: raspbian, headless

My setup 
PI 3B+
OS : Raspian

Trying to connect the pi headless using my laptop.
Both Pi and Laptop are connected to same wireless router.

Added the below config in `wpa_supplicant.conf` with correct credentials

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=<Insert country code here>

network={
 ssid="<Name of your WiFi>"
 psk="<Password for your WiFi>"
}
```

Also added ssh file to boot folder fo SD card.

On bootup can see Pi is connected to Wifi, router lists the Pi with IP address(192.168.0.101)
When I try to ping the Pi from Laptop using this IP,  get below error

```
Pinging 192.168.0.101 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.104: Destination host unreachable.
```

please help in setting the Pi in headless mode correctly.
Thanks

Comment: I believe you did not enable SSH. Please see and follow the procedure here: [Enable SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) Also, please post the actual supplicant file you used. It's not clear that you edited it correctly.

Comment: From the laptop, can you ping other devices on WiFi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

Comment: Does your router have a ping tool to ping the raspberry pi's address (`192.168.0.101`)?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109535/5538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the comments.

I got a clue from Ingo's comment.
Issue was with the router configuration which was blocking clients to ping each other.
Changed the router config and am able to ssh to my pi board

Special thanks to Ingo :) cheers :)

Comment: That security setting on the router was exactly my guess :-)